# How do I sort a text column with numbers (title 1, title 2, ...)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sorting

I want to sort a text column in natural sort order. Text column means, that the column was created as `TEXT` in SQLite. (`` Create Table...`id` TEXT ``).

```
title 1
title 2
..
title 10
```

I use this query:

```
'select id from t order by Cast(id as Integer)'
```

This returns title 1, title 10, title 2, ...

Here you can find a small [SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2a12ad/5).

Comment: I think thats not possible, cause You use `sqlite` on `Android.` Please look at [sqliteforum](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/cff93834d2b07da59d9bfc5f064cc1dd096ac054c45899a7130a2d7d17853f24) to see how it could work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alejandro.

Solved it in Java code using a custom `Comparator`.

GGK